# CakePHP Js->get() operation on div

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am reading the CakePHP manual about Js implementations, and I am trying to run some jQuery on a div, but I cannot get it working in my view. I have all of my Helpers and jQuery being pulled in.

As a test, I am just trying to get this element to fade in:

```
$this->Js->get('#resultsWrapper');
$this->Js->effect('fadeIn');

<div id="resultsWrapper">THIS IS A FADE IN TEST</div>
```

Its loading as normal..

Comment: Please show your code how you are including jQuery.

Comment: http://bin.cakephp.org/view/179167123

Comment: Does the javascript acutally get output to the browser? Where? Is it formatted correctly?

Comment: ROss, no thats the problem I cannot get it to output to the browser source. But if I echo it out with php it displays correctly (but not in the source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by altering the syntax of the prototype call. The manual suggested get() does not seem to work properly (at least from the hours and hours of experimenting I did)..

This is how I solved this: (note the loading and success sections).

```
 <?php 
   echo $ajax->submit('Submit', 
     array('url'=> array('controller'=>'records',
    'action'=>'add'), 'update' => 'ajax_div', 
    'evalScripts' => true,
    'loading' => 'Element.show(\'busy-indicator\')',
    'success' => 'Element.hide(\'busy-indicator\')'
    ));
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the element is `display: none;`

That will allow it to actually fade in rather than just be loaded

Comment: I can echo it out: ...$this->Js->effect('fadeIn'); and it prints to the screen, but if I do not echo it, it does not display in the source??

Comment: where are you running it. You need to run it in your view not your controller. Also you want to run it after the element is added to the DOM so the calls should go after the html

Comment: i am running it in my search.ctp. search() action is in the plans_controller. i cannot get the script to display no matter what i do this far.. if tried it in the default as well - no dice.

Comment: i am running it in my views?? i tested in the default layout and search view.